# Should I annotate errors in TypeScript in try/catch?

Tags: typescript, eslint

I fell into the hell of error handling and I still struggle to understand what the best goto approach is in 2022 for errors in a `try/catch` clause.

For example:

```
try {
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
}
```

Would it be advisable to annotate `error` with the type `Error`, or not? [eslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint) complains about `error` being of type `any`, and I shouldn't use `.message`.

So the solution would be:

```
try {
} catch (error: Error) {
    console.log(error.message);
///
```

Is the declaration really needed or just noisy code? It seems to me that `eslint` doesn't give me a choice .

Comment: Since any errors can be thrown inside the `try` block, say, `throw {type: '_error_'}`, `error` is by default of type `unknown`. If you want to access `message`, it is your responsibility to type it explicitly.

Comment: Understood, thx! I would accept this as an answer. Would `error.toString()` be the best way to stringify it then, or should I still go with `.message`?

Comment: It depends on how you want to display the error, say, if the error is `{type: '_error_'}`, `toString` will return `[object Object]`. In this case, you can simply use `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Perfect. I made a custom `getErrorMessage` function that I will use from now on.